# Notação de colchetes de acesso a objetos não aceita objeto String

Tags: javascript, objetos

Estou tentando chamar uma função que é uma propriedade de um objeto, passando um parâmetro para ela. Para isso eu uso a notação de colchetes mais isso: `(parâmetro)`.

Dessa forma:

```
afraid[day](num.toString())
```

Mas retorna erro:

> afraid[day] is not a function.

Tentei com template string também:

```
afraid[`${day}`](num.toString())
```

e também:

```
afraid[`"${day}"`](num.toString())
```

e dá o mesmo erro:

> TypeError: afraid[((""" +] is not a function

Só funciona se eu passo o nome da propriedade do objeto como um String literal, mas não é o que eu preciso:

```
afraid["Tuesday"](num.toString())
```

Vejam a função no objeto:

```
let afraid = {
    Monday: 12,
    Tuesday: function(number){
     if(number>95)return true
     else return false
    },
    Wednesday: 34,
    Thursday: 0,
    Fryday: function(number){
      if(number%2 == 0) return true 
      else return false
    },
    Saturday: 56,
    Sunday: 666
  }
```

E a tentativa de uso da função:

```
 if(afraid[day] == Math.abs(num) || afraid[`${day}`](num.toString()) == true) return true
  else return false
```

Comment: Nem todas as chaves de `afraid` são funções, o erro não ocorre só quando `day` não é 'Tuesday'  nem 'Fryday'? https://ideone.com/Jj09v3

Comment: Você tem certeza que o valor de `day` é o esperado?

Comment: Mas o seu objeto em si, as chaves das funções são strings literais, se vc tem um retorno das chaves literais dentro deste objeto day, bastaria fazer isso: `afraid[(day).toString()](num.toString())`

Comment: O que exatamente está retornando: `day`? que tem neste: `const day = "???"`

Comment: @hkotsubo. Faz sentido, porque nem todas as propriedades de day são funções, mas eu não achei iria dar erro ao testar num if.

Comment: @IvanFerrer day é uma string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No seu objeto `afraid` nem todos os valores são funções. O valor da chave `'Monday'`, por exemplo, é um número. Somente as chaves `Tuesday` e `Fryday` possuem funções como valor. Por isso só é possível chamar estas funções se a chave for `Tuesday` ou `Fryday`:

```js
let afraid = {
    Monday: 12,
    Tuesday: function(number){
     if(number>95)return true
     else return false
    },
    Wednesday: 34,
    Thursday: 0,
    Fryday: function(number){
      if(number%2 == 0) return true 
      else return false
    },
    Saturday: 56,
    Sunday: 666
};

// afraid['Tuesday'] é uma função, funciona
let day = 'Tuesday';
console.log(afraid[day](100)); // true

// afraid['Monday'] é um número, vai dar erro
day = 'Monday';
console.log(afraid[day](100)); // erro
```

O que você pode fazer é usar [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) para verificar se `afraid[day]` de fato é uma função, e só chamá-la se realmente for:

```js
function test(day, num) {
    let afraid = {
        Monday: 12,
        Tuesday: function(number) {
           return number > 95;
        },
        Wednesday: 34,
        Thursday: 0,
        Fryday: function(number) {
          return number % 2 == 0;
        },
        Saturday: 56,
        Sunday: 666
    };

    return afraid[day] == Math.abs(num) ||
           (typeof afraid[day] === 'function' && afraid[day](num));
}

console.log(test('Monday', 12)); // true
console.log(test('Tuesday', 100)); // true

console.log(test('Saturday', 12)); // false
console.log(test('Fryday', 11)); // false
```

Assim, eu só chamo a função `afraid[day]` se ela realmente for uma função.

Também simplifiquei seus `if`'s. Afinal, uma expressão do tipo:

```
if (condicao) return true;
else return false;
```

Pode ser simplifcada para:

```
return condicao;
```

E removi o `toString()` do `num`, pois dentro das funções você compara o valor com números, e não com strings, então não entendi para que converter para string ao passar para as funções.

---

Uma outra opção é usar o [operador ternário](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Conditional) no `return`:

```
return typeof afraid[day] === 'function' ?
       afraid[day](num) :
       afraid[day] == Math.abs(num);
```

Ou o bom e velho `if`/`else`:

```
if (typeof afraid[day] === 'function')
    return afraid[day](num);
else return afraid[day] == Math.abs(num);
```

---

<sup>*Por fim, não sei se foi erro de digitação, mas o correto é "Friday", e não "Fryday".*</sup>